# Button getting pressed when is created directly under an already long pressed button

Tags: react-native, button, touchablehighlight

I have a button (a TouchableHighlight) labeled `BOOM` and another button labeled `thinking`. Initially, the boom button is shown and on long press it should be replaced by the thinking button. And when the thinking button is pressed, it should be replaced again by the boom button. I have the following code:

```
{
this.state.thinking ?
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.thinkingOff} activeOpacity={0.9} underlayColor="#734F96" style={{borderRadius: 100}}>
        <View style={{...styles.sendButton, backgroundColor: '#e2b705'}}>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 9, color: 'white'}}>thinking</Text>
        </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
:
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.send} onLongPress={this.thinkingOn} delayLongPress={300} activeOpacity={0.9} underlayColor="#e2b705" style={{borderRadius: 100}}>
        <View style={styles.sendButton}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>BOOM</Text>
        </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
}
```

and the methods `thinkingOn` and `thinkingOff` simply toggle the state `thinking`.

The problem is that when the thinking button is shown and I take off my finger (after holding the boom button), the `onPress` belonging to thinking is fired

Comment: I see the problem, try using `onPressOut`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `onPressOut` or `onPressIn`.